# Inverse meromorphic function is injective, proof verification

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

I need to prove the following. Could someone verify the proof?

Could someone elaborate on the questions at the bottom?

> $f: \mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$ has an pole at $z_0$.
>
> Show $f^{-1}$ is injective at a punctured neighbourhood of $z_0$ if and only if $z_0$ is a simple pole.

### Proof

If $f$ has an isolated singularty at $z_0$ then by its Laurent-expansion it can be written as:
$$f(z) = \frac{g(z)}{(z-z_0)^N} \qquad \text{ for a certain holomorphic } g(z), g(z_0) \not = 0$$

---

$\color{red}{\Leftarrow}$ ($N = 1$)

Consider $\frac{1}{f(z)} = \frac{z-z_0}{g(z)}$ where $f^{-1}(z_0)=0\Rightarrow f^{-1}$ is holomorphic at $z_0$.

$$\left( \frac{1}{f(z)}\right)' = \frac{g(z) - (z-z_0) g'(z)}{g^2(z)}$$

Then $$\left.\left( \frac{1}{f(z)}\right)'\right|_{z=z_0} = \frac{1}{g(z_0)} \not = 0$$

Meaning $f^{-1}$ is injective in a neighbourhood of $z_0$.

---

$\color{blue}{\Rightarrow}$ (proving $N = 1$)

Consider $\frac{1}{f(z)} = \frac{(z-z_0)^N}{g(z)}$ where $f^{-1}(z_0)=0\Rightarrow f^{-1}$ is holomorphic at $z_0$.

Since $f^{-1}$ is injective in a neighbourhood of $z_0 \Rightarrow f^{-1}(z)'|_{z=z_0} \not = 0$.

Then $$\lim_{z\to z_0} \frac{N(z-z_0)^{N-1}g(z) - g'(z)(z-z_0)^N}{g^2(z)} \not  = 0\qquad \color{red}{(1)}$$

Since $g(z_0) \not = 0$ then  $\lim_{z\to z_0} N(z-z_0)^{N-1} \not = 0$ if and only if $N-1\leq = 0$ and since $N\in \{ 1,2,\ldots\}$, $N = 1$.

Q.E.D.

#### Questions

- The 'theorem' uses **puncture** neighbourhood of $z_0$, but I don't seem to be using this in my proof, am I missing something?
- $\color{red}{(1)}$ Is this the right way to prove $N=1$? (do I have to use this limit?)

Comment: You extend $1/f$  to $z_0$. This is fine, but it is then not really $1/f$ anymore which is why the result is phrased in the way it is phrased.